# Paperwork about JAX-RS frameworks and their client sided implementation

Tags: rest, jax-rs

I read Bill Burkes book "Restful Java with JAX-RS" (2009) and when he wrote about frameworks (RESTEasy, Apache CXF, Jersey), specially about frameworks which support the client side implementation, he said:

> There is a lot
>   of interest from the JAX-RS specification lead and expert group members to get a
>   standardized client framework baked into JAX-RS 2.0.

Am I right when I say, there isnt a standardized client framework yet? Will there ever be one?

I thought about writing a 60 pages long work about the different frameworks with regard to client side implementation. At the end maybe a prototype of an own implementation, with some good ideas. Do you think it's a good issue to discuss about? Do you have ideas what else I could consider in this discussion?

Comment: Assuming you meant “60 pages”, that's either far too long or too short. A full study will take more work than that, and nobody's ever going to read more than about a 1 page summary unless _very_ interested…

Comment: Thats bad... I have to write a paper about something including jax-rs, restful or frameworks for jax-rs, but just the client sided part, because I programmed the client (with wicket) of an restful web service last year. I thought that would be a good theme.

Comment: I couldnt find the comment edit button. Does anyone know a topic to discuss about client sided part of jax rs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you need to be very clear on what the objective of such a paper would be. Ie. what the interesting application of your findings would be.

Do you e.g. intend to submit it as input to the JAX-RS specification board, or publish it as a white-paper for solution architects or even as a scientific paper? If not, then I agree with Donal Fellows on that 60 pages is way too much, and that you otherwise probably will need more than that to establish your methodology, describe the experiments including how they relate to the objective, analyse your findings, and so on. And if you also want to try your own hand in creating a client framework, then you will quickly come close to the extend of a postgraduate thesis...

On the other hand, am I certain, that we are many practitioners, who are reluctant to embrace JAX-RS as long, as there are no mature ways of consuming the services it enable us to produce. It should however be possible evaluate the different options in a more accessible form than a 60-page report.

If you decide to go ahead with making some sort of paper about this, I (too?) will be interested in seeing the result.
Also, I am curious of, whether any of the JAX-RS frameworks supports "dynamic" clients based on runtime binding of URI templates delivered from the server.